# how to publish map in ros2 galactic?

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I installed ros galactic on ubuntu 20.04 using this bash script (https://github.com/turtlebot/TurtleBot4Lessons/tree/main/installation), then I ran turtlebot4 simulation in depot and map its surrounding. I saved the map with

**

```
ros2 service call /slam_toolbox/save_map slam_toolbox/srv/SaveMap "name:
  data: 'map_name'
```

**

then when I want to publish the map, and use

```
ros2 run nav2_map_server map_server $PWD/map_name.yaml
```

I get stuck with the following log

```
[INFO] [1662497993.651852411] [map_server]: 
    map_server lifecycle node launched. 
    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate
    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[INFO] [1662497993.651943245] [map_server]: Creating
```

here is the available service list:

```
ros2 service list
/map_server/change_state
/map_server/describe_parameters
/map_server/get_available_states
/map_server/get_available_transitions
/map_server/get_parameter_types
/map_server/get_parameters
/map_server/get_state
/map_server/get_transition_graph
/map_server/list_parameters
/map_server/set_parameters
/map_server/set_parameters_atomically
```

and here is the result of node list

```
ros2 node list
/map_server
```

Am I doing something wrong? should I add any other node to this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406036/how-to-publish-map-in-ros2-galactic?/) by [dastan_forum](https://answers.ros.org/users/116883/dastan_forum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2022-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

first create a map_server_params.yaml file to set the ros parameters,

```
map_server:
    ros__parameters:
    frame_id: map   
    topic_name: map
    use_sim_time: false
    yaml_filename: "/home/dastan/map.yaml"
```

then run the map_server node with passing the .yaml file as the input,

```
ros2 run nav2_map_server map_server --ros-args --params-file map_server_params.yaml
```

then since all nodes in nav2 are lifecycle nodes, you need to transition them into active mode,

```
ros2 lifecycle set /map_server configure
ros2 lifecycle set /map_server activate
```

then the subscriber to the /map topic should have the **QoS of local_transient** in order to recieve the map data.

---

Originally posted by [dastan_forum](https://answers.ros.org/users/116883/dastan_forum/) with karma: 19 on 2022-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-09-11**:
Good work! It was a bit more than I thought, you should self-accept this answer to your question

**Comment by [dastan_forum](https://answers.ros.org/users/116883/dastan_forum/) on 2022-09-12**:
Thanks @ljaniec

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to call correct service to load the map from file: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_map_server/README.md#services

> ### Services
>
> As in ROS navigation, the `map_server`
> node provides a "map" service to get
> the map. See the
> nav_msgs/srv/GetMap.srv file for
> details.
>
> NEW in ROS2 Eloquent, `map_server`
> also now provides a "load_map" service
> and `map_saver` - a "save_map"
> service. See nav2_msgs/srv/LoadMap.srv
> and nav2_msgs/srv/SaveMap.srv for
> details.
>
> For using these services
> `map_server`/`map_saver` should be
> launched as a continuously running
> `nav2::LifecycleNode` node. In
> addition to the CLI, `Map Saver` has a
> functionality of server handling
> incoming services. To run `Map Saver`
> in a server mode
> `nav2_map_server/launch/map_saver_server.launch.py`
> launch-file could be used.
>
> Service usage examples:
>
> `$ ros2 service call /map_server/load_map nav2_msgs/srv/LoadMap "{map_url: /ros/maps/map.yaml}"`
>
> `$ ros2 service call /map_saver/save_map nav2_msgs/srv/SaveMap "{map_topic: map, map_url: my_map, image_format: pgm, map_mode: trinary, free_thresh: 0.25, occupied_thresh: 0.65}"`

Usually everything is done in the Nav2 launcher https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/packages/configuring-map-server.html?highlight=map#map-server-parameters if you don't want to change maps at run-time.

> ###Map Server Parameters
> **yaml_filename** (...) - Path to map yaml file.
>
> **Note**: This parameter must appear in a yaml file when launched with Nav2’s default launch files. It is overridable as a launch configuration map, which is only possible if the yaml_filename key already exists in the yaml file. If you would like the specify your map file in yaml rather than in launch defaults or launch configurations, remove the launch default so it is not overridden in Nav2’s default launch files. This is an odd quirk that exists to be able to provide users with the option to change maps at run-time on the commandline.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dastan_forum](https://answers.ros.org/users/116883/dastan_forum/) on 2022-09-08**:
when I call

ros2 service call /map_server/load_map nav2_msgs/srv/LoadMap "{map_url: /ros/maps/map.yaml}"

I receive waiting for service to become available..., how to activate the service server for this?

**Comment by [dastan_forum](https://answers.ros.org/users/116883/dastan_forum/) on 2022-09-10**:
??????????

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All nodes in Nav2 are lifecycle nodes - you must transition them up into the active state. Also, I think you need to specify that map as a param argument.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2022-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dastan_forum](https://answers.ros.org/users/116883/dastan_forum/) on 2022-09-08**:
I did as you said, there's just one problem, it only publishes the map once!

**Comment by [dastan_forum](https://answers.ros.org/users/116883/dastan_forum/) on 2022-09-08**:
I will reply thorough answer on how to do as your comment tomorrow

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-09-08**:
It should only publish once, its a transient local QoS topic, any late joining subscription should be able to get it.

**Comment by [dastan_forum](https://answers.ros.org/users/116883/dastan_forum/) on 2022-09-08**:
it doesn't! Only the early subscription are able to get it

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-09-09**:
Are you subscribing with a transient local QoS?

**Comment by [dastan_forum](https://answers.ros.org/users/116883/dastan_forum/) on 2022-09-10**:
thanks Steve